# Sorting and grouping array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I know ho to do basic sorting and grouping, but this is something I can't find the right logic for.

```
const test = [
    {name: 'a', type: '1'},
    {name: 'a', type: '2'},
    {name: 'a', type: '3'},
    {name: 'b', type: '1'},
    {name: 'b', type: '2'},
    {name: 'c', type: '3'},
    {name: 'd', type: '1'},
    {name: 'e', type: '4'},
    {name: 'e', type: '3'},
    {name: 'f', type: '1'},
    {name: 'f', type: '2'},
    {name: 'f', type: '3'},
    {name: 'g', type: '2'},
];
```

above the array I have and below the results I would like to get.

```
const clean = [
    {type: '1-2-3', names: 'a'},
    {type: '1-2', names: 'b'},
    {type: '3', names: 'c'},
    {type: '3-4', names: 'e'},
    {type: '1', names: 'd'},
];
```

I have a file with many double names that need to be grouped. and I need an object with unique groups and names.

lets say name a, b, c. a has group 1,2,3 - b has 2,3 c has 1,3
we create 3 groups, groupName '1-2-3.' , '2-3', '1-3' and add the names that fit inside the group so we don' have a double name

I hope you guys understand what I mean. Please some help in what login I use to sort/group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `reduce`, to perform the grouping. Like this:

```js
const test = [
    {name: 'a', type: '1'},
    {name: 'a', type: '2'},
    {name: 'a', type: '3'},
    {name: 'b', type: '1'},
    {name: 'b', type: '2'},
    {name: 'c', type: '3'},
    {name: 'd', type: '1'},
    {name: 'e', type: '4'},
    {name: 'e', type: '3'},
    {name: 'f', type: '1'},
    {name: 'f', type: '2'},
    {name: 'f', type: '3'},
    {name: 'g', type: '2'},
];

const response = test.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.type - b.type;
}).reduce((agg, current) => {
  if(agg[current.name]) {
    agg[current.name] = `${agg[current.name]}-${current.type}`
  } else {
    agg[current.name] = current.type;
  }
  return agg
}, {});

const groupedData = {};
Object.entries(response).forEach(([k, v]) => {
  if(groupedData[v]) {
    groupedData[v].push(k);
  } else {
    groupedData[v] = [k];
  }
})

const output = [];
Object.entries(groupedData).forEach(([k, v]) => {
  output.push({type: k, names: v})
})
console.log(output);
```

Comment: It almost works. the thing is the new created type only holds 1 name, in my case there might be multiple names per the newly created group.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and output for that?

Comment: I added "f" which should be added to the same group as "a"

Answer (score 0):

no need to overkill

```js
const test = [
    {name: 'a', type: '1'},
    {name: 'a', type: '2'},
    {name: 'a', type: '3'},
    {name: 'b', type: '1'},
    {name: 'b', type: '2'},
    {name: 'c', type: '3'},
    {name: 'd', type: '1'},
    {name: 'e', type: '4'},
    {name: 'e', type: '3'},
    {name: 'f', type: '1'},
    {name: 'f', type: '2'},
    {name: 'f', type: '3'},
    {name: 'g', type: '2'},
];

  const groupping = test
    .sort((a, b) => a.name - b.name)
    .reduce((previous, {name, type}) => {
      const groupByName = previous.findIndex(item => item.names === name);
      if (groupByName > -1) {
        previous[groupByName].type += `-${type}`;
        previous[groupByName].type = previous[groupByName].type.split('-').sort((a, b) => a - b).join('-')
      } else {
        previous.push({type, names: name});
      }
      return previous;
    }, []);

const result = groupping.reduce((previous, obj) => {
    const groupByType = previous.findIndex(item => item.type === obj.type);
    if (groupByType > -1) {
        previous[groupByType].names = [...previous[groupByType].names, obj.names]
    } else {
        previous.push({...obj, names: obj.names})
    }
    return previous;
}, [])

  console.log(result);
```

Comment: same thing here, it works only now the type is not unique, I need the names as array inside the type

Comment: But this is the cleanest solution yet

Comment: @MaygaFatmawati i've edited it, u can try

Comment: type '1-2-3' should contain names: ['a', 'f'] and the type should be unique

Comment: @MaygaFatmawati almost same with the first i sent

Answer (score 0):

Using reduce you can build an object to look up. Since your array is not sorted, it needs to be sorted so you can build the strings in numeric order.

```js
const test = [
    {name: 'a', type: '1'},
    {name: 'a', type: '2'},
    {name: 'a', type: '3'},
    {name: 'b', type: '1'},
    {name: 'b', type: '2'},
    {name: 'c', type: '3'},
    {name: 'd', type: '1'},
    {name: 'e', type: '4'},
    {name: 'e', type: '3'},
];

const result = Object.values(  //converts the look up object just in to an array of the values
  [...test] // copy array
  .sort((a,b) => a.name === b.name ? +a.type - b.type : a.name.localeCompare(b.name)) //have to sort it to get type in correct order
  .reduce((acc, { name, type }) => { // use look up with the name
  if (acc[name]) {  // have we seen it, just add the type to the string
    acc[name].type += "-" + type;      
  } else {  // if it is new, create a new object
    acc[name] = { names: name, type };
  }
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in two steps:

- First create a temp object (with name as key) to append an array of types
- Second, iterate the temp object to create an array (while doing so, make sure to use `.join("-")` to *join* the elements with dashes)

```js
const test = [
    {name: 'a', type: '1'},
    {name: 'a', type: '2'},
    {name: 'a', type: '3'},
    {name: 'b', type: '1'},
    {name: 'b', type: '2'},
    {name: 'c', type: '3'},
    {name: 'd', type: '1'},
    {name: 'e', type: '4'},
    {name: 'e', type: '3'},
    {name: 'f', type: '1'},
    {name: 'f', type: '2'},
    {name: 'f', type: '3'},
    {name: 'g', type: '2'},
];
```

```js
function group(data){
    // First, create a temp object
    const tempObj = {}
    // Then iterate list
    for ( const {name, type} of data){
        // Set value if not exists
        tempObj[name] ??= []
        // Append type
        tempObj[name].push(type)
    }

    // Second, iterate the object and generate result
    const result = []
    for (const key in tempObj){
        result.push({
            names: key, 
            types: tempObj[key].sort().join("-")
        })
    }
    return result;
    // Optional, if you want to sort by names
    return result.sort((a, b) => a.names - b.names)
}
```